# Active Voltage to Current Converter Formula

Tags: operational-amplifier

I try to understand miscellaneous applications using op-amp and on this website https://wiki.analog.com/university/courses/electronics/text/chapter-4 I am confused by the circuit below.

[image: circuit]

The given formula is for calculting the load current is

---

[image: formula] when [image]

There is no explanation that how it is obtained on the website.
It looks complicated and is different from the feedback configuration I have seen before which only normally 1 loop.

I have no idea how to start tackling the problem. What I know is V+ = V- because of high gain of the op-amp.

Comment: Research howland current pump: http://michaelgellis.tripod.com/howland.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One little correction to start, V+ = V- (approximately) but not because they have high impedance but because the opamp has high gain.

You missed the part of the explanation from the linked article saying R1 = R3. R2 = R4, Rs = Rs'

Substituting those values in your circuit we can see that if the op amp inputs are at the same potential, current flow left through R1 (R3) is Vt/R1 for the negative terminal and (Vt - Vin)/R1 for the positive terminal (where Vt if the voltage at the op amp input terminals). The difference in these currents is Vin/R1. This current flows through R2 and R4.

As R2 and R4 are equal, the difference in drop across R2 and R4 is given by 
Vin / R1 * R2. As the op amp inputs are at the same potential then the difference in potential between the top of Rs' and the bottom of Rs is also equal to
Vin / R1 * R2

The difference in potential across Rs will be (Vin / R1 * R2) + IR2 * Rs'

Dividing this by the value of Rs give current in Rs = 
(Vin / R1 * R2) / Rs + IR2 =

(Vin R2) / (Rs R1) + IR2

Iout = IRs - IR4

IR4 = IR2 - (Vin / R1)   [Because IR4 = IR3]

Iout = (Vin R2) / (Rs R1) + IR2 - IR2 + (Vin / R1)

= (Vin / R1) ( R2 / Rs  + 1)

= (Vin / R1) (R2/Rs + Rs/ Rs)

= (Vin / R1) (R2 + Rs) / Rs

= (Vin / Rs) (R2 + Rs) / R1

Comment: thanks for the remainder that I forget to mention R1 = R3. R2 = R4, Rs = Rs' and point out my false concept. I don't understand "The difference in these currents is Vin/R1. This current flows through R2 and R4". Why Vin/R1 flows through R2 and R4? What is the purpose to obtain the current difference?

Comment: We can analyze an OpAmp circuit by writing expressions for the voltages at the input terminals, then assume Vin+ = Vin - and form equations and  sove them. In the case of this circuit the expression for Vin+ involves Vout (Voltage at Iout). We know  that this term does not appear in the answer, otherwise it would not be a good current source. So we want to analyse Iout based on Vin. The circuit is in the form of a differential amplifier. The gain is R2 / R1 and the differential V at right hand end of R2-R4 is (Vdiff at left of R1-R2) * (-R2/R1), assuming R1 = R3, R2 = R4. I started from there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - it`s a tricky circuit. In, principle, it is a classical Negativ-Impedance-Converter (NIC) that is operated at the stability limit. This is because (see the linked document) R1=R3 and R2=R4 and Rs*=Rs. In this case, the positive feedback equals the negative feedback factor.

However, as soon as we connect a load at the indicated terminal, the positive feedback factor will become smaller and the circuit will be stable.

This can be also verified based on the shown expression for Zout which will be infinite for the given conditions (denominator is zero). An ideal current source has an infinite output resistance.